# Autofill message telegram

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to autofill the message input box is telegram bot chat by passing the parameters in the bot's url.

I don't want to send the message but just fill the user input with some values.

For eg: https://t.me/some-bot?message=Authorize

Comment: no you can't! instead use inlinekeyboard buttons with callbackdata equal to your message's content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `https://t.me/Bot?start=message` format, it will send `/start message`, but show `/start`. For instance, try [this link](https://t.me/Sean_Bot?start=factor_20170717).

Reference: [deep linking documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)

Comment: Ah, never mind. Just checked the get_updates endpoint. It works. Thanks!